# Discretization of a control module

Tags: control

The desired control is $u_f=\frac{1+\eta s}{1+hs}a$, where $u_f$ is the feedforward control, $a$ is the feedforward observation and $\eta$ and $h$ are two constant parameters. However, I can only observe $a$ but not $\dot{a}$. How to realize this in discrete time?

The method I use now is the zero-order hold method, which yields the discrete-time transfer function as $H(z)=\frac{\eta z/h-\exp(-T/h)+1-\eta/h}{z-\exp(-T/h)}$. This result is the same as that of Matlab funtion c2d. With $H(z)$, I can calculate $u$ without knowing $\dot{a}$. Is it the right way to do it?

Moreover, the control system contains other modules such as the plant dynamics $x = Gu$ and feedback control $u_b = Ky$, where $u=u_f+u_b$. Can I discrete these modules one by one and then synthesize them?

Answer (score 1):

> I can calculate u without knowing a˙. Is it the right way to do it?

Sure!

> Moreover, the control system contains other modules such as the plant dynamics x=Gu and feedback control ub=Ky, where u=uf+ub. Can I discrete these modules one by one and then synthesize them?

Usually, we tend to first synthesize the controller in the s-domain and then discretize the continuous blocks with a given sample time $T$.

This pipeline is reported in https://robotics.stackexchange.com/a/4434/6941.

As a side note, consider using the [Tustin formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_transform) for the discretization instead of the ZOH as the former method generally provides better results.